# Why did TypeScript move to GitHub?

Tags: github, typescript, codeplex

TypeScript was hosted on CodePlex for years, but recently moved to GitHub.

Is GitHub a **technically better**, more suitable platform, **or**

is it because CodePlex is Microsoft's page, and a lot less **popular** because of that?

The next version of ASP.Net (https://github.com/aspnet/Home)  is being developed on GitHub. Is appealing to the open-source community a new high priority for Microsoft?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft's motivation for using GitHub.

Comment: Where would it be on-topic?

Comment: Considering it's about why a private company did something, you probably need to find a press release or blog post explaining their motivation. Or talk to somebody at Microsoft. Beyond that, this is idle speculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Chris! I thought this topic to be much more straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

More OSS developers. Developers developers developers.